# FancyBox Issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

We inherited a website that was not functioning at all in IE8 (it would load a blank page). We corrected many of the issues but a couple still linger, the major being a featured product tab on the homepage right side that is not working correctly in IE8. It is using Fancybox 1.3.4.

This is the original code for it on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.tab").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'marginRight': '230px'
        },800);
        $(this).removeClass("unselected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("div.featured_product").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
    },
    function(){
        $("div.featured_product").fadeOut(800);
            $(this).animate({
                'marginRight': '-70px'
            },800);
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("unselected");
    });     
    $("a#single_image").fancybox();
</script>
```

Comment: maybe related but you only need to load a single instance of fancybox either uncompressed or minimized version but not both

Answer (score 0):

fancybox is working,
the problem you have is related to css IE filter

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)
```

try to remove it and change button to image instead of rotating it (it's not working in IE 9 also)